# How to highlight only one button in android

Tags: android

In my project based on database values,i am dynamically creating buttons.Now here by pressing one button,i am highlighting that button.suppose if i press another button then this button will be highlighted, and first pressed button will be unhighlighted.

My question is: always pressed button will be highlighted until another button is pressed.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        final Button b = new Button(this);          
        b.setWidth(80);
        b.setId(i + 1);         
        b.setText("M" + arr[i]);            
        ll.addView(b);      

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                  b.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.buttonbtn);

                  String str = b.getText().toString().substring(1);
                  Constant.diametervalue = str;
                  f1 = l.indexOf(Constant.diametervalue);
                  f2 = l.size();Log.e("","f1 value--"+f2);
                  Constant.length = f2;
                  InnerList adapter11 = new InnerList(this, str); 
                  adapter11.getCount();
                  gallery.setAdapter(adapter11);    
        }
    }
```

With my code by pressing one button it's highlighted.later if i press second button first and second buttons are highlighted.

Comment: How do you highlight a button?

Answer (score 1):

button elements having state pressed state only. In checkbox, there is a state called state checked.  Better you can create a checkbox with button images.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use checkbox with group not normal button view. if this not clear I can make some code for you .. but basically you will use checkbox and change the style to agree with that you want to show .. in this case you will be able to highlight(check) and when click on other button(checkbox) the first check will be gone if you use all them in a group

=======adding code=======

here we go my friend:

on mainactivity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

public class HighListButtonActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
    private CheckBox b1,b2,b3;
    private int selectedChId=-1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        b1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ck1);
        b2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ck2);
        b3=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ck3);

        b1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        b2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        b3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

  @Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // here just to follow the checkbox which is checked to uncheck it later when other checkbox is checked..
      if(selectedChId==-1){
          selectedChId=buttonView.getId();
      }else if(selectedChId==buttonView.getId()){
          selectedChId=-1;
      }else{
          ((CheckBox)findViewById(selectedChId)).setChecked(false);
          selectedChId=buttonView.getId();
      }

      //make your logic here......

}


}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <CheckBox 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="bt1"
        android:button="@drawable/hlor"
        android:background="@drawable/hlor"
        android:id="@+id/ck1"        
        />
    <CheckBox 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="bt2"
        android:button="@drawable/hlor"
        android:background="@drawable/hlor"
        android:id="@+id/ck2"        
        />
    <CheckBox 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="bt3"
        android:button="@drawable/hlor"
        android:background="@drawable/hlor"
        android:id="@+id/ck3"        
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

hlor.xml(as selector style):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/hlord" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/hlornd" />
</selector>
```

hlord.xml(as checked style drawable):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
<shape>
  <android:solid android:color="#FF555555"/>
</shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

hlornd.xml(as unchecked style drawable):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
<shape>
  <android:solid android:color="#FF000000"/>
</shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

for highlighting just change colors of hlornd/hlord styles

good luck...

Comment: sorry i didnt get u,can u explain.i cant use checkbox

Comment: on every button iam placing database values.so by pressing that button, its values will be display on screen. so only that button should be highlight

Comment: for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
 final Button b = new Button(this);  
b.setWidth(50);     
 b.setId(i);   
b.setText("M" + i);   
ll.addView(b); 
 b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){          
 EnabledButton=b.getId();          
  DeselectButtons();   
  b.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);            
         }
         public void DeselectButtons() {
             for(int i=0; i<5;i++){               
                     if (EnabledButton!= i)          ((Button)findViewById(i)).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
             }         
         }     
     });

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Suppose take two buttons Button1 and Button2.

and create four drawable for 2 buttons:

example: normal images: buttonone_normal, buttontwo_normal.

selected images: buttonone_selected,buttontwo_selected

```
 and onClickListeners put something like this:
buttonone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
  buttonone.setImageResource(R.drawable.buttonone_selected)
  buttontwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.buttontwo_normal)
}
buttontwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
  buttonone.setImageResource(R.drawable.buttonone_normal)
  buttontwo.setImageResource(R.drawable.buttontwo_selected)
}
```

Comment: Here iam creating buttons dynamically.How can i write individual onclicklistener methods. for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        final Button b = new Button(this);         
                b.setId(i );                                     here only i can write b.onclicklistener().

Comment: if buttons already created in xml file then ur code will aplly.Plz once check and tell solution

Comment: different id for every button, right? then handle with that id